# Problemas con las pruebas unitarias Array Junit

Tags: java

Mi duda y problema es el siguiente, tengo el metodo llenarVector donde lleno un vector con numeros aleatorios y ahora quiero hacerle la prueba unitaria con Junit que es el metodo testValidos, y me salta siempre un error y no se si es por que el assertArrayEquals no puede recibir el mismo vector o por que es.Si me podeis ayudar os lo agradeceria.

```
public void llenarVector(int vector[]) throws Exception{  

 Random aleatorio=new Random(); 
 int n=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
//     System.out.println(vector.length);
 if (vector.length<=MAXIMO){            
    for(int i=0; i<vector.length; i++)
    {    
            boolean existe=true;
            while (existe)
                {               
                n=aleatorio.nextInt(MAXIMO);     /* Siguiente valor aleatorio */
                existe=comprobar_existe(vector,n);
                }
            vector[i]=n;
     }

 }else 
     throw new Exception("Maximo 100 elementos");
```

}

```
@Test
public void testValidos() throws Exception{
    System.out.println("Llenar vector");
    int[] vector1 = new int[3];
    int[] vectorResult= new int[3];
    VectorUtilidades instancia1 =new VectorUtilidades();
    instancia1.llenarVector(vector1);
    assertArrayEquals(vector1,vector1);
}
```

[image: error del netbeans]

Comment: _y me salta siempre un error_ Si en vez de la bonita imagen pusieras el mensaje de error sería más fácil ayudarte. Si le das al signo de + al lado de VectorUtilidadesTest podría haber información valiosa.

Comment: Perdona no me fijara, ya lo he cambiado, y por lo que veo me da error otra prueba que tengo pero de todas maneras no se por que no me muestra el error de la prueba que deseo ver.

Comment: `assertArrayEquals(vector1, vectorResult);` o... viceversa.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias lo probare